# Why 意大利 and not e.g., 意国

Tags: translation, characters, transliteration

I always wondered why all main European countries are spelled in chinese with a Hanzi that identifies them or some about their origins more the 国 morpheme,

Italy has a uncontested importance in European history, nevertheless its name has been just transliterated to 意大利, which IMHO reveals less participation in its codification.

Is it a matter of when the name was transposed to Chinese language? Maybe it's just the minor influence of the country in that period? I tried to search some information but I couldn't find anything (furthermore, my chinese level reading is extremely low).

### UPDATE

The information and [the page](http://blog.sina.com.cn/s/blog_547c338d01000828.html)  suggested by @user2619 unfolded my research on the topic:

Seems like all the country names were just transliterated at first. The former name of the well know *什么*国 countries was, e.g.,:

```
美利坚 --> 美国
法兰西 --> 法国
日耳曼 --> 德国
不列颠 --> 英国
[...]
```

Later, above for all countries with more strict relations with China, these names were translated to a form more similar to 中国 possibly as a form of bigger respect.

I was teached at a chinese course that the particular 汉字 characherizing the country was somewhat chosen because of some historical reason. For example 法 for the country which invented the constitution. But chinese people I asked say this is not true and has to do with nothing but phonetic reasons. Then as seen in [[1](http://blog.sina.com.cn/s/blog_547c338d01000828.html)] in some case like 希腊， the sound is taken from the endonym rather than exonym.

Comment: This it the fact and convention. you just need to accept and remember it

Comment: probably relevant (and possibly even a duplicate to a degree): http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/5822/origin-of-beautiful-kingdom-and-hero-kingdom

Comment: I want to add that the 德 comes from Deutschland. I believe that Chinese Diaspora have contributed to the naming of countries as well. Since I'm from Malaysia, I can tell you that people either call Malaysia 马来西亚 or 大马.

Comment: There is one interesting case. 葡萄牙（Portuguesa）also called "葡国", but this is not common unless in limited cases (葡国蛋挞 - Portugue egg tarts).

Comment: 德意志 (Deutsche) --> 德国 not 日耳曼 (German), 英格兰 (England) --> 英国 not 不列颠 (Britain)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's just historical stuff. European countries that have commerce with China prior to the Ching dynasty and also modern countries after WWII, in general have fancier names.

```
希腊 for Greece
意大利 for Italy
瑞典 for Sweden
法国 for France
美国 for US
葡萄牙 for Portugal
马来西亚 for Malaysia
日本 for Japan
```

etc.

You just have to accept them as it is. It's hard to find a pattern why.

Edit: http://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/countrynames_chinese.htm

There's very few countries which have 国 in their names, it's more of a short form, like 英格兰 for 英国, 美利堅合眾國 for 美国. Others which have 共和国 in their names are People's Republic, like China, whose official name is People's Republic of China.

Comment: Reading my question again I see why you're both concerned about my acceptance of the fact. :) Yes, I supposed it was a matter of relationship in a particular hystorical moment, but your confirmation is illuminating.

Comment: This reminds me about learning what Greece is called in Mandarin. When I was younger, I learned both English and Mandarin at the same time, so I realize that most countries have their names sound similar if not the same in both English and Mandarin. I was so confused why Greece was named the way it is cause it sounds nothing like the English spelling.

Comment: If you can somewhat read some chinese, this link has some great explainations on the chinese name origins of some of the countries. They are very different from English. http://blog.sina.com.cn/s/blog_547c338d01000828.html

Comment: I’ve always found the Chinese name for Russia (俄國 èguó)  somewhat strange in that it seems to be devoid of positive associations like you find with 美 and 英.  There’s probably an interesting story behind the Russian word for China (Kitai) too.

Comment: I prefer using 俄罗斯 instead of 俄國 for Russia. 

    亦有一說，認為是轉譯自All Russia。 - From Wikipedia

俄 - All, 罗斯 -Russia.

Comment: Yes I saw. Thanks to these further information, I deepen my search, see **update**.

Comment: 俄罗斯 for Russia is adopted from Mongolian.